# ActionMailer::Base Not Loading smtp_settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, actionmailer

I am running into a very strange problem.

My /config/environments/production.rb file has the following =>

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address   => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port      => 587,
:domain    => "domain.com",
:user_name => "username",
:password  => "password",
:authentication => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

I've restarted the app (currently using Passenger and Nginx), but when I go into Rails Console I get the following =>

```
[30] pry(main)> ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
{
             :address => "localhost",
                :port => 25,
              :domain => "localhost.localdomain",
           :user_name => nil,
            :password => nil,
      :authentication => nil,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Anyone ever experience this ?  This is the root problem for me not being able to send email out.  I get connection refused since it is not loading the proper settings.  Any thoughts  I am banging my heard against the wall ><

Comment: Do you open the console in production environment with `rails c production`? What does `Rails.env` in the console return?

Comment: Probably unnecessary but still - makes sense to define your config as part of your actual Rails config, not just tacked on to AM::Base. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you using your rails console in production mode.

```
rails console production
```

Comment: I had created an alias to automatically run it in production, we moved boxes and did not re add Alias :) Thank you for pointing it out !